# Access Fragment's Menu within a FragmentStatePagerAdapter

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-menu

I use a `FragmentStatePagerAdapter` to display fragments inside a `ViewPager`.

These fragments display 2 additional icons on top of the ones coming from the parent `Activity`.

These 2 icons are showed/hidden according to fragment displayed, so I tried to keep the `Menu` inflated in memory in order to modify it dynamically.

On my `ViewPager`, 3 fragments are always loaded, only the middle one is displayed.

The problem is the following: it seems that `onCreateOptionsMenu` and `onPrepareOptionsMenu` are called only for the first `Fragment` created, because of this, I get null pointers when I try to get the menu on the other fragments. Please see the code below:

```
@Override
    public void onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu, MenuInflater inflater) {
        //Get the 2 icons for the rates
        inflater.inflate(R.menu.rate_fragment, menu);
        //Get activity's icons
        super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu, inflater);
        mMenu = menu;
    }
```

Here are the functions I use to hide/show the menu items:

```
private void hideOption(int id){
        MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(id);
        if(item != null){
            item.setVisible(false);
        }
    }

    private void showOption(int id){
        MenuItem item = mMenu.findItem(id);
        if(item != null){
            item.setVisible(true);
        }
    }
```

But these functions fail as soon as the system tries to load the second `Fragment`.

My guess is that the menu is only created once for the `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`, but then how can I modify dynamically the menu? Do I have to modify it using the Activity?

Thanks!

Comment: Hiding and showing is automatic as the fragment moves in and out of view. Other than calling `setHasOptionsMenu(true)` on the fragments with action bar items (and not calling it for those that do not), there is nothing more that is needed. See https://github.com/commonsguy/cw-omnibus/tree/master/ViewPager/ActionBar How does your scenario differ from this?

Comment: My fragments are using a `ViewSwitcher` that allows to switch between a visualization view and an edition view. The 2 menu items are used to switch between these 2 views. It means every fragment Menu must change according to the status of the fragment (new fragment --> edition view, old fragments --> visualization view).